# Fields of Parent Class not recognized

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pure-virtual

I've benn having a problem for a while, when I'm trying to inherit from a pure virtual class, when I make the constructor for the "son" classes I receive this error:

```
../src/Course.cpp:54:77: error: class ‘ElectiveCourse’ does not have any field named ‘_dptr’
```

And this happens for all of the Course Protected fields.

This is the structure:

Course.h:

```
    class Course{
    public:
        virtual void reg(Student * s) = 0;
    ..
    protected:
    ...
        string _dptr;
    ...
    };
```

and then:

```
class ElectiveCourse : public Course{
...
}
```

Course.cpp:

```
ElectiveCourse::ElectiveCourse(
    string name,
    int semester,
    double minGrade
)
: _dptr("CS"), _name(name), _semester(semester), _minGrade(minGrade) {
}
```

Like the ElectiveCourse, I have two other classes that inherit from the Course class, and I'm getting the same error in all of them.
[EDIT] This only happens in the Constructor of them.
There is NO constructor in the Course class hence it is pure virtual.

In the other hand, I also have two classe: Student, and CSStudent : Student, where Student is also pure virtual and CSStudent inherit Student, and in this case there are no errors. I did the same exact thing in both of them.
What seems to be the problem?
I'm sorry for my grammar errors.

[EDIT]
added the Course.cpp part where I'm getting the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the real relevant code. And correct your spelling

Comment: "There is NO constructor in the Course class hence it is pure virtual." Why shouldn't pure virtual classes have a constructor? Pure virtual just means that you have to derive from the class in order before you can create objects from it -- the "base" part of these objects, however, still needs to be constructed, and for that a constructor might be necessary.

Comment: Btw, in C++ every class has a constructor. If you do not declare one explicitly, the compiler adds a default constructor. The only thing you can do is restricting access to the constructor from the outside world by declaring a constructor protected or private. So your "pure virtual" class does have a constructor (the default-generated), and even a public one!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize member variables of one class in another class. If you want to initialize the member variables  of Course in a constructor, you have to add a constructor to Course. You can make that constructor protected if you like.

The alternative (probably better) would be to change your design to make Course an interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can't initialize the fields of your parent class in the subclass constructor. The reason for that is that the construction order includes the construction of base class before you can actually address its inner fields. And construction of the base requires construction of its inner fields. That said, to achieve what you need, you should create a constructor in your base class that accepts all of your parameters (name, semester etc.) and invoke this constructor from your subclass constructor:

```
Course::Course(string name, 
               int semester,
               double minGrade):
               _dptr("CS"), 
               _name(name),
               _semester(semester),
               _minGrade(minGrade){}

ElectiveCourse::ElectiveCourse(string name,
                               int semester,
                               double minGrade):
                               Course(name, semester, minGrade){}
```